# How to programmatically (and idiomatically) navigate to an external URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React microservice. At some point we verify the user data to have a certain value, otherwise we want to redirect to an external URL. That sounds easy, but I am not sure if my current solution is idiomatically correct.

React router doesn'T seem to provide anything beyond the current domain. I can only change the path, using the history object. Is there something I overlooked?

I am using `window.location.href` now to get the current URL, as I need to pass this as a callback, and `window.location=xyz` to navigate. but it feels wrong.

```
// ComponentX.js

...

if (name === null) {
  window.location = selectOrgURL(window.location.href);
}

render (
...
```

Comment: I think you just want to use a normal HTML `a` element.

Comment: How would that help me?